# How do I solve the problem of selenium on GCP

Tags: python, selenium, google-cloud-platform

I use Google Cloud Platform(Debian linux) to run Selenium to Scrape Dynamic Data. The first few thousands of data are normal, but after that, the data cannot be captured and there is no error. Why the RAM to 60% will break and data all missing! What should I do? Thanks!

A part of code:

```
for i in job_id:                                                                                         
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    browser.get('example.website.com')`
```

[image]

Comment: maybe scraped page recognized that you use script/bot and it blocks data.

Comment: Thank you for responding! 
This is unlikely as the process had been running for more than a few hours  and the same IP can still scrape it as well.

Comment: you could use `logging` (or normal file) to save some information for every job/loop. OR maybe google cloud already saves some some information in some `log` - maybe Chrome stop working and this is why you get free memory and no data.

Comment: I see.  I'll try to recreate the problem in this way.  What do you think the problems could be for chrome to stop working?